# Page responds with just a hash

Tags: templates

Sometimes when I view my EE site on a local server, and less so on my live environments, I receive a 200 response which is looks like this:

{c1a3de9f993f7deec04da3d5075ac7f9948848712}

The next time I refresh the error goes away.

Does anyone have ideas of what causes this, or how to prevent it.

I use Stash, which may be related to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to fix

Disable template caching on all templates.

### Problem #1: Why is the template rendering as {c1a3d...8712}?

This bug was caused by EE's Template Caching feature and Stash.

Stash has two parsing stages. The first stage will replace the contents of a template with variables ('{c1a3d...8712}') that get parsed in the post-process stage.

If template caching is enabled for a template then EE will cache the template output *before* the post-process stage. When the template is loaded from the cache then Stash is unable to successfully execute the pre- and post-process stage and the half-processed template is displayed.

### Problem #2: Why is this occurring intermittently?

When Template Caching is enabled and the 'Refresh Interval' is set to zero then is might appear that caching is disabled.

[image]

However, EE checks the timestamp of the last generated cache vs. the current timestamp. Therefore if page is loaded multiple times in 1 second, the `time()` vs `time()` is `0` and the cached template is loaded.

Actual code: `elseif (time() > ($timestamp + ($refresh * 60)))`

Turn off caching to avoid this.